# lodash property search in array and in nested child arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test 1',
        children: []
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'test 2',
        children: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'test 4'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'test 3',
        children: []
    }
]
```

How can I filter by the `id` property in both this array *and* the nested `children` arrays?

For example, searching for `id = 3`, should return the `test 3` object, and searching for `id = 4` should return the `test 4` object.

Comment: Is the nesting depth of the `children` arrays fixed to one level, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: @AdamBoduch it is fixed to one level

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using lodash, you can do something like this:

```
_(data)
    .thru(function(coll) {
        return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || []);
    })
    .flatten()
    .find({ id: 4 });
```

Here, [thru()](https://lodash.com/docs#thru) is used to initialize the wrapped value. It's returning the union of the original array, and the nested children. This array structure is then flattened using [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten), so you can [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find) the item.

Comment: Excellent! For lodash v4.0 replace `pluck` with `map`.

Comment: Also, I need to mention that unfortunately this is slower for small arrays than iterating.

Comment: Bare in mind that this implementation is going only one level deep. If your tree is more than one level deep it won't work as intended.

Comment: You could use flattenDeep or flattenDepth

Comment: This code does not work if we have 1 more nested child to find

Answer (score 6):

That's a very simple [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) task. The easiest way to solve it is recursion (link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vegikoceko/1/edit?js,console)). It will work with any depth (with recursion limit of course) and it's one of the fastest ways with the worst complexity O(n):

```
function find(id, items) {
  var i = 0, found;

  for (; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === id) {
      return items[i];
    } else if (_.isArray(items[i].children)) {
      found = find(id, items[i].children);
      if (found) {
        return found;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Update:

To find all matches - a slightly modified function (jsbin link above is updated):

```
function findAll(id, items) {
  var i = 0, found, result = [];

  for (; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id === id) {
      result.push(items[i]);
    } else if (_.isArray(items[i].children)) {
      found = findAll(id, items[i].children);
      if (found.length) {
        result = result.concat(found);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: It will return only one item. What if I need all the matching elements?

Comment: @Ashwin, please see the update of the answer. But keep in mind that in case of `findAll` the whole tree would be analyzed (`find` would stop at the very first matching).

Answer (score 6):

Another `lodash` option with children key and unlimited levels deep.

```
const flattenItems = (items, key) => {
    return items.reduce((flattenedItems, item) => {
        flattenedItems.push(item)
        if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
            flattenedItems = flattenedItems.concat(flattenItems(item[key], key))
        }
        return flattenedItems
    }, [])
}

const item = find(flattenItems(items, 'children'), ['id', 4])
```

Comment: Great, this works as adviced!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using pure javascript with ES6 syntax:

- First you can flatten the array with `.reduce` function
- Then you can use `.find` to search for id you want to find

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1',
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2',
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'test 4'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test 3',
    children: []
  }
]

const flattenData = arr.reduce((newArr, arr) => {
  const {children, ...rest } = arr;
  newArr.push(rest);
  return newArr.concat(children)
}, [])


console.log(flattenData.find(d=>d.id===4))
```