# Accessing object in array of arrays using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure and am trying to remove an object in participants (league.division.participants).

```
var participantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
player: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' },
record: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ParticipantRecord' },
events: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' } ]
});

var divisionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    participants: [ participantSchema ]
});

var leagueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    startDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    endDate: Date,
    locked: Boolean,
    leagueType: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'LeagueType' },
    game: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' },
    divisions: [ divisionSchema ],
});

mongoose.model('League', leagueSchema);



var _RemoveDivisionParticipant = function(participantId)
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        Models.League.findOne({'divisions.participants._id':participantId})
            .populate('divisions')
            .populate('divisions.participants')
            .exec((err, league) => {
                if (err) {return reject(err)}   
                league.divisions(XXXXX).participants(participantId).remove();
                console.log(league.divisions[0].participants[0])
            })
    })
}
```

This is what i have so far, but obviously it returns the league object, and i have no way of getting to the participants since I don't know which division the participant is in (Shown by XXXXX in the sample). Any pointers as to what I should do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714938/lodash-property-search-in-array-and-in-nested-child-arrays

may be this can help

Comment: Read the answers in this related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763721/mongoose-delete-array-element-in-document-and-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove an array element based on a condition :

```
League.update({
    'divisions.participants._id': participantId
}, {
    $pull: {
        'divisions.$.participants': {
            "_id": participantId
        }
    }
}, { multi: true }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Follow up question. As I typed up your solution, I accidentally used 'division' instead of 'divisions' in the pull, yet mongoose did not return an error. Any idea why?

Comment: There is no error dispatched if nothing match your query (why would it be ?) but in the result, the number of modified result `res.nModified` will be 0

Comment: Still have a relational DB mindset, so i expected an error when he didn't find it. Thanks again