# How can I use Lodash/JS to recursively filter nested objects?

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array, filter, lodash

I have an array with objects of unknown depth, like this

```
var objects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar',
    childs: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'baz',
        childs: [{
            id: 4,
            name: 'foobar'
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I would like to be able to filter a specific child object by it's id.

Currently I am using this little lodash script (referred from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714938/lodash-property-search-in-array-and-in-nested-child-arrays)) but it works only with objects not deeper than one level. So searching for `id: 1` and `id: 2` would work fine while searching for `id: 3` or `id: 4` would return undefined.

```
function deepFilter(obj, search) {
    return _(obj)
        .thru(function(coll) {
            return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children'));
        })
        .flatten()
        .find(search);
}
```

[A little JSfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vy5wj91u/15/)

Comment: do you want to get the object with the questioned `id`?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function find(id, array) {
    var result;
    array.some(o => o.id === id && (result = o) || (result = find(id, o.children || [])));
    return result;
}

var objects = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar', children: [{ id: 3, name: 'baz', children: [{ id: 4, name: 'foobar' }] }] }];

console.log(find(1, objects));
console.log(find(2, objects));
console.log(find(3, objects));
console.log(find(4, objects));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the function recursively in order to target child object. Try following

Iterate over the array and for each object check whether the `id` is found. If yes, break and return the result, else continue to search in the `child` (if exists).

**Approach 1 : Traverses the tree branch by branch**

Using this approach, first the code traverses for first element till the last child, then second element this last child and so on.

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,name: 'foo'}, {id: 2,name: 'bar',childs: [{id: 3,name: 'baz',childs: [{id: 4,name: 'foobar'}]}]}];

function findObject(arr, id) {
  var result;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].id === id) {
      result = arr[i];
      break;
    }
    if(arr[i].childs) {
      result = findObject(arr[i].childs, id);
      if(result) break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(findObject(objects, 4));
```

**Approach 2 : Traverses the tree depth by depth**

Using this approach, first the code traverses for first level elements, then second level elements and so on.

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,name: 'foo'}, {id: 2,name: 'bar',childs: [{id: 3,name: 'baz',childs: [{id: 4,name: 'foobar'}]}]}];

function findObject(arr, id) {
  var result;
  var children = [];
  for (let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].id === id) {
      result = arr[i];
      break;
    }
    if(arr[i].childs) {
      children = [...children, ...arr[i].childs];
    }
  }
  if(!result && children.length) {
    result = findObject(children, id);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(findObject(objects, 4));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that recursively like so:

```
function deepFind(arr, search) {
    for(var obj of arr) {
        if(search(obj)) {
            return obj;
        }
        if(obj.childs) {
            var deepResult = deepFind(obj.childs, search);
            if(deepResult) {
                return deepResult;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
var result = deepFind(objects, function(obj) {
    return obj.id === myId;
});
```

**Example:**

```js
function deepFind(arr, search) {
    for(var obj of arr) {
        if(search(obj)) {
            return obj;
        }
        if(obj.childs) {
            var deepResult = deepFind(obj.childs, search);
            if(deepResult) {
                return deepResult;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var objects = [{id: 1,name: 'foo'}, {id: 2,name: 'bar',childs: [{id: 3,name: 'baz',childs: [{id: 4,name: 'foobar'}]}]}];

console.log("ID 1:", deepFind(objects, obj => obj.id === 1));
console.log("ID 4:", deepFind(objects, obj => obj.id === 4));
console.log("ID 7:", deepFind(objects, obj => obj.id === 7));
```

Comment: I like this solution most since I am not tied to the object attribute within your function. Thank you Ibrahim!

Comment: You're welcome! This is the closest I could get to lodash's `find` flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You can have a recursive function and check for the child

```js
var objects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bar',
  childs: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'baz',
    childs: [{
      id: 4,
      name: 'foobar'
    }]
  }]
}];
let tempArray = [];


function doRecursiveSearch(obj, id) {

  obj.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item)
    if (item.id === id) {
      tempArray.push(item)
    } else {
      if (item.childs && Array.isArray(item.childs)) {
        console.log(item)
        doRecursiveSearch(item.childs, id)
      }
    }

  })
}
doRecursiveSearch(objects, 4)
console.log(tempArray)
```