# print array of objects root with childen

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript array of objects
main array is root have children

```
Array(2) [ 
    { id: "3", children: [] }, 
    { id: "8", children: [{ id: "476", children: [] }] } 
]
```

I want to print all with loop

I try this code

```
    let idx= [];
       for(var i = 0; i < root.length; i++){
                idx[i]=root[i].id;

        }
            console.log(idx);
```

this code print root ids
but I want all root and children ids

​

Comment: Try recursion to print the children. Can the nesting be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: I tried recursion but not doing good for me

Comment: This answer does a good job of answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68956654/20039554

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of each parent from a nested array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955025/how-to-get-the-value-of-each-parent-from-a-nested-array-of-object)

Comment: @khalidseleem please share your recursive attempt so people can help resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursivly iterate over the array:

```js
function get_id(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].id);
    if (arr[i].children[0]) { 
      // if got at least one child, iterate over children array.
      get_id(arr[i].children);
    }
  }
}

let test_arr = [
  {
    id: "3",
    children: [
      {
        id: "333",
        children: [
          { id: "999", children: [] },
          { id: "321", children: [] },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  { id: "8", children: [{ id: "476", children: [] }] },
];

get_id(test_arr);
```